# AKFFTTap stops generating data after some time

Tags: audiokit

I'm using AudioKit for a recorder app, and I added a AKFFTTap to the AKMicrophone for drawing a custom audio waveform. This all works well, but after several recordings, or after some time passes with the app recording screen open, the FFT data suddenly becomes all 0. I know the mic is working and the gains don't change, since the recorded file contains the expected audio. It seems like just the FFT tap stops working all of a sudden.

Anyone have any idea why this is and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I can only guess that something happens that is like a notification and makes a route change thereby stopping the tap.  Is this on a phone, could a text message or other even be coming in?  Does it change if you go into airplane mode?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka it is on a phone, but there definitely isn’t any notification or call coming in. I’ll check in airplane mode to make sure. If the tap is stopped, do you know how to restart it? The AKFFTTap class doesn’t have any isStarted method to check, or any reset method... if I just reassign it, I get a crash.

Comment: Does it happen on a simulator too? Once we know the cause we could change AKFFFTTap to adapt if its nothing we have direct control over.  Can you share a project that outlines the problem?

Comment: Aurelius,
First, thanks for the quick replies and all your assistance!
Unfortunately, I'm on a very tight schedule with my App and I can't create a sample project right now - but after we release sometime next week I'll be able to do that.
In the meantime, what I'm trying to do, and hope you can help me with, is simply reset the components every time the user starts a recording. I'm trying to do this, but the second time I record, the FFT doesn't work again. So maybe if I figure this out, we'll know what happens in the former case as well. So, here's what I'm doing:

Comment: I'll detail that issue in a separate question.

Comment: The new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715721/akffttap-stops-working-when-initialized-second-time