# How do I re-initialize a Tap?

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to resolve an issue detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705736/akffttap-stops-generating-data-after-some-time?noredirect=1#comment86434820_49705736), where my FFT tap stops working after a while.

One thing I want to try and do is simply re-initialize the tap whenever recording starts.

How can that be done? Is simply initializing a new tap (thus deallocating the old one) the proper way to do it? like this:

```
    func recordingStart() {
        fft = AKFFTTap(myNode)
        //proceed with recording code
    }
```

Trying this I get a crash. The node (a AKMicrophone) is verified to be stopped. I tried stopping the AudioKit engine and restarting it after this call, with the same resulting crash.

Crash details:

[avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAEGraphNode.mm:804:CreateRecordingTap: (nullptr == Tap())]

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()'

So, how do I recreate a tap?